# Get part of a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I feel like this is a really silly question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere!

Is it possible to get a group of chars from a char array? to throw down some pseudo-code:

```
char arry[20] = "hello world!";
char part[10] = arry[0-4];
printf(part);
```

output:

```
hello
```

So, can I get a segment of chars from an array like this without looping and getting them char-by-char or converting to strings so I can use substr()?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, no.  C-style "strings" simply don't work that way.  You will either have to use a manual loop, or `strncpy()`, or do it via C++ `std::string` functionality.  Given that you're in C++, you may as well do everything with C++ strings!

**Side-note**

As it happens, for your particular example application, you can achieve this simply via the functionality offered by `printf()`:

```
printf("%.5s\n", arry);
```

Comment: Alright, that's too bad. Oh well, I can convert to string, I was just wondering if there was a more... elegant solution. 
and I'm trimming a part off of the char array to use later, so just using printf's abilities won't solve it. But thanks for that tidbit anyway, I didn't know about that and it might come in handy!

Comment: @Curlystraw: @Moo-Juice's answer below uses C++ strings, and is pretty damn elegant, if you ask me!

Answer (score 24):

You could use `memcpy` (or `strncpy`) to get a substring:

```
memcpy(part, arry + 5 /* Offset */, 3 /* Length */);
part[3] = 0; /* Add terminator */
```

On another aspect of your code, note that doing `printf(str)` can lead to format string vulnerabilities if `str` contains untrusted input.

Answer (score 5):

As Oli said, you'd need to use C++ `std::string` functionality.  In your example:

```
std::string hello("Hello World!");
std::string part(hello.substr(0, 5)); // note it's <start>, <length>, so not '0-4'

std::cout << part;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do mention the two obvious approaches. The only thing I can think of would be to define your own substring type to work off character arrays:

```
struct SubArray
{
    SubArray(const char* a, unsigned s, unsigned e)
        :arrayOwnedElseWhere_(a),
        start_(s),
        end_(e)
    {}
    const char* arrayOwnedElseWhere_; 
    unsigned start_;
    unsigned end_;
    void print()
    {
        printf_s("%.*s\n", end_ - start_ + 1, arrayOwnedElseWhere_ + start_);
    }
};
```