# How to print string first n bytes when the string's length is greater than n?

Tags: c, string, byte, printf

So I have a string that has a certain amount of bytes (or length). I say bytes because there is no NULL terminator at the end of the string. Though, I know how long the string is. Normally, as we all know, when you `printf("%s", str);`, it will keep printing every byte until it gets to a NULL character. I know there is no C string that is not NULL terminated, but I have a weird situation where I'm storing stuff (Not specifically strings) and I don't store the NULL, but the length of the "thing".

Here is a little sample:

```
char* str = "Hello_World"; //Let's use our imagination and pretend this doesn't have a NULL terminator after the 'd' in World
long len = 5;

//Print the first 'len' bytes (or char's) of 'str'
```

I know you are allowed to do something like this:

```
printf("%.5s", str);
```

But with that situation, I'm hard coding the 5 in, though with my situation, the 5 is in a variable. I would do something like this:

```
printf("%.(%l)s", len, str);
```

But I know you can't do that. But gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: A very similar question has been answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4777218/2163085

Comment: SO 4777218 is related, but somewhat different (referring primarily to assignment rather than printing).

Comment: You can use `snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%.%ds", len);` to create the appropriate format string, and then use `format` in the call to `printf()`.  If you're doing `scanf()`, you practically have to do this if the input lengths vary (the `*` in `scanf()` is very different from the `*` in `printf()`).  OTOH, the `printf("%.*s\n", len, str)` mechanism is usually most appropriate for `printf()`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`printf("%.*s", len, str);`

and also, there is no C string that is not NULL terminated.

Comment: I know there is no C string that is not NULL terminated, but I have a weird situation where I'm storing stuff and I don't store the NULL, but the length of the "thing".

Comment: @RobAveryIV you can print `len` amount of string from `str` like above

Comment: Note that this works because every * in the format adds another required argument that is replaced with the integer value provided by `len` above.

Comment: I guess that's what the `*` is for?

Comment: @RobAveryIV yes that is why the `*` :-P

Comment: Does it matter if `len` is a `long` or `int`?

Comment: @RobAveryIV not that I know of - it can be either and it will still work. Just one question, can you store a string in memory with greater than MAX of `unsigned int`? or `0xFFFFFFFF` length?

Comment: I want to say yes. Though you probably would have to implement it by creating two strings, and concating them and removing(or overwriting) the NULL thats between them (the one left over from the first string). I've never tried, but even so, that would be a huge string.

Comment: @RobAveryIV your memory wouldn't fit :-) especially if it is a 32 bit computer. But that apart, `size_t` which is what `strlen` returns, is of type `unsigned int` so, even if the size of the string is much bigger than `unsigned int` I do not think there is an `strlen_l` for long strings.

Comment: The type of the argument for a `*` _must_ be an `int`.  The return from `strlen()` is not an `int` (it is `size_t`), so you must cast it if you use it.  Either the variable `len` must be of type `int` or you need to cast it in the call to `printf()`.  Things can go horribly wrong if you move from 32-bit to 64-bit (Unix) platforms and a length is `long` instead of `int`; the alignment of everything else in the argument list is off-kilter, leading to dramatically erroneous results (or core dumps).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
{
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
```

Which will print them in the same line, looping for whatever lenght you need to print.

Comment: This can be much slower than the accepted `"%.*s"` answer because of the many calls to printf (buffer flush is not the issue I think)

Answer (score 0):

You could detect null byte poisoning like this. Program wil display Poisoning Null Byte detected

```
  char filename[] = "path/image.php\0.bmp";

  if ((sizeof(filename) - 1) == strlen(filename)) {

      printf("%s %s", "No poisoning Null Byte detected" , "\n");

      FILE *fp;
      fp = fopen(filename, "r");

      if ( fp == NULL ) {
        perror ( "Unable to open the file" );
        exit ( 1 );
      }

      fread ( buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp );
      printf ( "%s\n", buf );

      fclose ( fp );

  } else {
      printf("%s %s", "Poisoning Null Byte detected" , "\n");
  }
```