# Printing a char variable in C doesnt show properly

Tags: c, string, compiler-errors, printf, undefined-behavior

So my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch[5] = "funny";
    printf("gum: ");
    printf("ze numbre is %c \n", ch);
}
```

as far as I learned, it should print:

```
gum: ze numbre is funny
```

but instead of outputting the `ch` variable, if outputs some strange symbol (it looks like a small red square with square FF and sometimes F5 written on it), any tip? I'm coding in VSCode

Comment: `%s`, not `%c`. But `[5]` isn't enough to hold `"funny"`, as you need room for the null terminator.

Comment: `ch` is a pointer to a `char`

Comment: A higher warning level may help detect this. I get, `warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]` on this code.

Comment: `char ch[5] = "funny";` to `char ch[] = "funny";` Get the compiler to calculate the length of the array

Comment: ok i got it working, thank you Fred and Ed, stay dripped and have a good one

Answer (score 1):

First I compiled your code :

```
gcc c.c -Wall
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:7:27: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
    7 |     printf("ze numbre is %c \n", ch);
      |                          ~^      ~~
      |                           |      |
      |                           int    char *
      |                          %s
```

Then changed c to s ( as compiler and Fred Larson said):

```c
   #include<stdio.h>

   int main(){
    char ch[5] = "funny";
    printf("gum: ");
    printf("ze numbre is %s \n", ch);
   }
```

then recompile ( no errors ) and run

```
gcc c.c -Wall
./a.out
gum: ze numbre is funny
```

Works as expected ... but it still not error free as Ed Heal and Fred Larson said: it can give undefined behavior. So next try: let "the compiler to calculate the length of the array"

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char ch[] = "funny";
    printf("gum: ");
    printf("ze numbre is %s \n", ch);
    
}
```

You can do it in  [explicit way](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

```c
char ch[6] = {'f', 'u', 'n', 'n', 'y', '\0'};
```

or manually udjust length of the array ( include one place for null sign, [which is is added automatically at the end of each string in C](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-string-how-to-declare-strings-in-the-c-programming-language/).

```c
char ch[6] = "funny";
```

There is also [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376765/how-to-print-string-first-n-bytes-when-the-strings-length-is-greater-than-n)

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char ch[5] = "funny";
    printf("gum: ");
    printf("ze numbre is %.5s \n", ch);
    
}
```

Is it good ?

Comment: Except you got lucky, because `ch` is still not null terminated. I got garbage on the end of the line when I did the same change: `gum: ze numbre is funny�# �# �c `

Comment: Please see my comment above to correct the code

Comment: @Fred Larson What is the reason of such difference ? gcc ?

Comment: @Adam: It's just undefined behavior being undefined. Could be different compilers, compiler options, or other factors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `printf` conversion specifier `%c` expects a single character passed as an `int` such as `'c'`. You are passing `ch`, an array of `char`, which is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element when passed as a function argument. You should use `%s` for this argument.

Note also that `char ch[5] = "funny";` does not create a proper C string as there is not enough space in `ch` for the 5 characters in `funny` and the null terminator. It is safer to let the compiler compute the length of the array with

```
char ch[] = "funny";
```

You could also define a `char` pointer and initialize it to point to a string literal:

```
char *ch = "funny";
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch[] = "array";
    const char *p = "pointer";

    printf("gum: ");
    printf("ch is an %s\n", ch);
    printf("p is a %s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```